# Need help retrieving values from <option> tag

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask, HTML, CSS, Jinja & SQL for my assignment. I need help retrieving the values from HTML/Jinja in order to use them in my SQL queries (in python) I hope the code helps you understand better..

HTML/Jinja

```
<section id="filters">
  <select id="Genre" name="genres" onchange="window.location.reload(true)">
    {% for row in genre %}
      <option value="{{row.genre}}">{{row.genre}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</section>
```

Python/Flask

```
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
  db = get_db()
  select = request.form.getlist('genres')
  general = db.execute (
      """
      SELECT Movies.Movie_ID, Movies.Name, Movies.Rating_IMDB,
      Movies.Rating_RT
      FROM Movie_Genre
      JOIN Movies ON Movie_Genre.Movie_ID = Movies.Movie_ID
      JOIN Genres ON Movie_Genre.Genre_ID = Genres.Genre_ID
      WHERE Genres.Genre = ?;
      """,
      (str(select),)
      ) 

  genres = db.execute("SELECT Genre FROM Genres")

  basic = general.fetchall()
  genre = genres.fetchall()
  return render_template('index.html', basic=basic, genre=genre)
```

Comment: I had a look at the answer but couldn't quite figure it out

Comment: Could you post the rendered HTML of the select box?

Comment: Also: I'd suggest you start by looking at "request.POST.items()".